# Following Android drag and drop example, error "btn_default_pressed cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android-listview, android

Working in min API 15, I'm trying to find how I can drag and drop one item element out of a ListView list onto a TextView above it (just to copy the text into it).

I'm trying to follow this example:

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/10/drag-and-drop-honeycombics.html

Namely these two parts...

http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/trunk/HCDragDrop/src/com/beanie/hcsample/dragdrop/MyDragShadowBuilder.java

http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/trunk/HCDragDrop/src/com/beanie/hcsample/dragdrop/HCDragDropActivity.java

However, I can't figure out how to fix this error

```
The import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder cannot be resolved
```

Or if I remove the import then DragShadowBuilder gives me

```
DragShadowBuilder cannot be resolved to a type
```

I changed my minSDK And target SDK both to '15'.  Should I not have access to these classes now?  How can I resolve this error?

edit:  I've fixed that problem- properties, android, set target.  Clean, refresh.  Ok.

But now I'm getting

```
btn_default_pressed cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

on
   mShadow = v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_default_pressed);

Comment: Can you confirm that you have a drawable by that name?

Comment: Can't say I could, since I don't.  I see it now in his project under
 svn/  trunk/ HCDragDrop/ res/ drawable-mdpi/ btn_default_pressed.9.png
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that class came in API 11. So probably you have one of a couple problems.

1. You have set the SDK target in your manifest, but you haven't updated your actual SDK. If this is the case, go to the SDK Manager and get the necessary updates.
2. You project is still linked to a API 10 or lower jar. If this is the case go into, Project > Properties > Android and pick the correct library.

Project > Clean and restarting Eclipse can't hurt either.

Comment: No problem, was about to :)